# Is there a more efficient way to remove localization from a NIB or Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I've picked up an iOS project that was previously localized for 20 languages, but not yet translated. While reviewing before submitting for translation, I discovered that most of the NIBs and storyboards that are localized have generated strings for a lot of placeholder text that is not used runtime. Since many of the files are only placeholder text strings, the localization just needs to be removed. I'm aware that this can be done by removing the individual language localizations, deleting the reference to the file in the project, moving the file up a directory from Base.lproj, and re-adding it. However, since there are 20 languages and 40+ resource files, removing the localization in this manner is relatively tedious and time-consuming.

Obviously I can just fix it as mentioned above, but I would love to avoid the tedium in the future. Does anyone know of a better way to un-localize a resource file? If not in Xcode, a command line solution would be equally appreciated; anything that doesn't require thousands of repetitive mouse clicks.

Comment: You could write a script with Apple Automater to do the tedious steps you mention.

Comment: Hey bro did you get any solution on it. I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: @kallol, I'm afraid not. I ended up managing it manually a few more times, and eventually started writing a utility to manage translations across multiple platforms that would have gotten around the problem. Unfortunately, I left the company where I was working on it before it was done, so all I have to show for it is a pile of half-baked C#.